# Error in installing Eworld

Tags: java, openstreetmap

When I try to install eworld (framework to import mapping data from providers, such as OpenStreetMap.org  (OSM), visualize it, edit and enrich it with events or annotational attributes and pass it to traffic simulators, such as SUMO or VanetMobiSim.) , following problem occured. I have already installed Java 7.

Error:
The registry refers to a nonexistent Java RUntime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.

The system cannt find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

Implying you're using windows; your JAVA_HOME enviroment variable probably arent set correctly.

@edit

see this: https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GDRAD/java.htm#BGBFJHAB